# Coloring pivot table pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I have a pivot table created using pandas which looks like below:

```
**Account** AA-PRD  AB-PRD  AC-PRD  AD-PRD

**Product** 10      20      30      50

PROD1       50      50      60      12

PROD2       44      78      567     678

PROD3       56      234     45      77
```

I want to apply color for the entire column based on account name starts with. Ex: If account name starts with "AA" color=yellow, if starts with "AB" then  color = red

How can I do that in python and save it into excel file? "Account" has been used as "columns" in pd.pivot_table function. Used below code to create the pivot table

```
df_summary_table = pd.pivot_table(df_final,values=["cost"],index = "Product", columns="Account")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create DataFrame of styles with [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) and set rows by masks with `loc`:

```
def color(x): 
   c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
   c2 = 'background-color: red'
   c = ''
   m1 = x.columns.str.startswith('AA')
   m2 = x.columns.str.startswith('AB')

   df1 = pd.DataFrame(c, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
   df1.loc[:, m1] = c1
   df1.loc[:, m2] = c2
   return df1

(df_summary_table.style.apply(color,axis=None)
                 .to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False))
```

Comment: Here "x" is the input pivot table dataframe right? @jezrael

Comment: @greenking - no, `df` is `df_summary_table`

Comment: and then in function `x` is also `df_summary_table`

Comment: Thanks a lot @ jezrael

Comment: Say for example I want to have list from this pivot table like below:                         list1 = [AA-PRD,AB-PRD,AC-PRD,AD-PRD] , How can I that @jezrael?

Comment: @greenking - Do you think `L = df_summary_table.columns.tolist()` ?